# Read text file with javascript

Tags: javascript, text-files, filereader

I have this peace of code which works:

```
    document.getElementById("fileId").addEventListener('change', function(){//"change" menar att det körs när något ändras, i detta fall när texfilen laddas
    var fr = new FileReader();
    fr.onload = function(){
        var txtFile = document.getElementById("fileContent").textContent = this.result; //Text File is the full text document printed on the website
        var SingleRow = txtFile.split("\n"); //Make every line of the text document to an "item" in the array "Singlerow"
        console.log(SingleRow[4]);//print pupil 5 in Console
        Space(SingleRow);
    }
    fr.readAsText(this.files[0]);
})
```

The problem is i need this to be within a "onclick-activated-function" if that makes sense and if I have understood everything correctly that won't work because I can't have a onclick-function as a nested function. Is there any way to solve my problem?

If you need to see more the code just tell me.

Comment: So you want it to happen on click instead of on change?

Comment: sorry for the late answer. I think what i need to do is to somehow replace this line: document.getElementById("fileId").addEventListener('change', function(){       so it activates by a click. so i can save a the variable  "singleRow" togheter with another variable i got from another functions which collects data from a textfield. But i'm on deep water so what do i know;)

Comment: Edit nvm i'm stupid and fixed it, thanks for your time anyway